# ggplot2 grouped boxplot. Dots from individual boxplots within the same group are pooled together

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

In R, I have a data frame like this:

```
Ratio= c("1/1","1/1","1/1","1/1","1/5","1/5","1/5","1/5","1/10","1/10","1/10","1/10")
Exp=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Val=c(1,1,1,1,0.645,0.89,1.45,2.67,5.43,6.3,8.4,9.5)
Time=c(1,1,24,24,1,1,24,24,1,1,24,24)

df=data.frame(cbind(Time,Ratio,Val,Exp))

df[,c(1,3:4)] = apply(df[,c(1,3:4)], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

With ggplot2, I want to create a grouped boxplot showing the individual measurements (dots) within each box. However, the dots from the same group (Time) but different subgroups (Ratio) are pooled together:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Time), y=Val, color=factor(Ratio)))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(family="Arial",colour="black",size=(13)),
        axis.title = element_text(family="Arial",colour="black",size=(15)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(t=0,r=0,b=5,l=1)),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())+
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.9, outlier.shape = NA,
               fill=c("lightsalmon1","azure2","skyblue1",
                      "lightsalmon1","azure2","skyblue1")) +
  ylim(0, 10) +
  geom_jitter(color="black", width = .05, alpha = .8) +
  labs(y= "expression (fold change)", x = "Time") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "ratio")
```

How to assign dots to their corresponding boxes?

Comment: You could use `geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge())` for the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_boxplot` uses `position="dodge"` by default whereas `geom_jitter` uses `position="jitter"`. Hence, to align your dots   with the boxplot y<ou have to dodge the points too, which in case of `geom_jitter` means to switch to `position=position_jitterdodge()`.

Additionally, not sure why you added a vector of fill colors to `geom_boxplot` which you then overwrite by `scale_fill_discrete`. A more easier approach would be to map on the `fill` aesthetic and set your colors via ´scale_fill_manual`.

Finally, there is no need to wrap vectors in `cbind` when creating a data frame. This will save you from having to convert the columns of your dataset afterwards.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Time, Ratio, Val, Exp)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Time), y = Val, fill = factor(Ratio))) +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(family = "Arial", colour = "black", size = (13)),
    axis.title = element_text(family = "Arial", colour = "black", size = (15)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 5, l = 1)),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.9, outlier.shape = NA
  ) +
  ylim(0, 10) +
  geom_point(
    color = "black", alpha = .8,
    position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .05, dodge.width = .9)
  ) +
  labs(y = "expression (fold change)", x = "Time") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("lightsalmon1", "azure2", "skyblue1"),
    name = "ratio"
  )
```

[image]